# Can somebody help me change the opacity of the Google Dictionary Extension for Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, google-chrome

I've tried going through the CSS, HTML, and Javascript files in the extension but nothing I try seems to work. I have very little experience with CSS, HTML, and Javascript, so I was wondering if anybody would be able to figure out how to change the opacity of the popup that comes up when you double click a word with that extension. Thanks!
This is the extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-dictionary-by-goog/mgijmajocgfcbeboacabfgobmjgjcoja?hl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change `background:#ffc!important;` in `content_css_main.css` to something with opacity like `rgba(255, 255, 204, 0.5)!important;` that should do the trick. You might have to restart Chrome (at least) or repackage it to get the change to take effect.

Comment: Thank you so much! Would you know how to change the opacity of the text too? Thanks.